# Mapping longitude and latitude from .csv data to geo_point type not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

This is the fourth time I attempt to do these mapping. But I do not hav my previous configuration files.

classes2.conf

```
    input {
  file {

    path => "D:\Workspace.Elastic\FinalVersions\classes.csv"    
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {

    csv {
        columns => ["TITLE","PROFFESSOR","MAJOR","SEMESTER","student_count","unit","rating","submit_date","latitude","longitude"]
        separator => ","


    }   

    mutate {
        convert => { "longitude" => "float" }
        convert => { "latitude" => "float" }
        rename => {
            "longitude" => "[location][lon]"
            "latitude" => "[location][lat]"
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "geopointest"
    }
}
```

classesRating_mapping2.json

```
{
  "class": {
    "properties": {

      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> [location] is defined as an object in mapping [doc] but this name is already used for a field in other types"

I have created geopointest index and added the json mapping like this:

```
curl  -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/geopointest/class/_mapping --data-binary @classesRating_mapping2.json
```

What am I missing?
Many thanks.

Comment: You need to create the index with the proper `location` mapping **before** running  logstash.

Comment: @Val Updated my question

Comment: That command actually tries to modify the existing `class` mapping. If the `location` field already exists as an `object` it won't work.

Comment: @Val There is no other class mapping.. since I run logstash after running that command. Is it?

Comment: You need to delete your index first (to get rid of the wrong mapping), then you can run your command and finally, run logstash

Comment: @Val I did that a lot today. Now i minimized everything. .csv file only has two items each row, json mapping has only location.. And the problem persists.

Comment: I see another issue, you also need to specify `document_type => "class"` in your `elasticsearch` output otherwise logstash will create a type `log` by default. Probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Val Create an answer with your comment. That was the problem. And I believe last time i did this I had the exact same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your mapping you're using `class` which is a custom type name. That means you need to modify your `elasticsearch` output like this:

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "geopointest"
    document_type => "class"        <-- add this line
}
```

Without that line, Logstash uses the `log` type name and that was the reason why your mapping was off.